# How to add td rowspans to a table?

Tags: php, html-table

I was thinking of a way to make td rowspans with the same items?.. I mean

look at this table below, this how the output looks like, just an example.

[image: img]

how can I make the output look like this, so handling things will be easy..

[image: img]

---

code here

```
$get = file_get_contents('URL');
$json = json_decode($get, true);

$items = $json['Catalogue'][0]['Accessories'];
$quantity = $json['Accessories'][1]['Quantity'];   
$price = $json['Accessories'][2]['Price'];
echo 
"<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th width=200px>Items</th>
    <th width=100px>Quantity</th>       
    <th width=100px>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>".$items."</td>
    <td>".$quantity."</td>      
    <td>".$price."</td>
  </tr>  
</table>";
```

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of the `$json` array that you are working with? It doesn't appear there will ever be more than one title row and one body row.

Comment: it's an api request from a server, so more items bought it will show them as json

Comment: But you need to illustrate how you do this. At this point you don't even have a loop in your example so I can't see how you even create the table in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use rowspan to create the desired table you like. See below demo.

Two things you need to note,

1. Add `rowspan="N"` to the starting row where you going to show the `TD`. N is number of rows to merge
2. Don't include `TD` for the next `N` row. There should be only one `TD` for the merged row and that `TD` should have the `rowspan`.

You need to take care of the above 2 rules in your iterate when rendering the table.

```css
td, th { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:200px">Items</th>
    <th style="width:100px">Quantity</th>       
    <th style="width:100px">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Sports Watch</td>
    <td>1</td>      
    <td>$89.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td>2</td>      
    <td>$179.98</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>    
    <td>3</td>      
    <td>$267.97</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Portable Digital Camera</td>
    <td>1</td>      
    <td>$196.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>      
    <td>$393.98</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```