# how to make a div sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div table like for a page, is it possible to make it sortable like html table with javascript?

I moved from normal table because it was not possible for me to continue using it due to this [How to add td rowspans to a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094361/how-to-add-td-rowspans-to-a-table) and thus used the div table.

so I used this div table and the only thing im missing is how to make it sortable so I can sort it by item or price.. like datatables, tablesorter e.t.c

```
<div class="Header">    
    <div class="item"><a href="#">Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="desc"><a href="#">Description</a>
    </div>      
    <div class="price"><a href="#">Price</a>
    </div>    
    <div class="status"><a href="#">Status</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Info">
  <div class="itemName">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemInfo">
    <div class="List">
      <div class="Desc">Description 1</div>
      <div class="Box">                
        <div class="price">$79</div>
        <div class="status">16 in stock</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

full code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/empqyN?editors=110 and here http://jsfiddle.net/a4fcxzra/

Comment: It is possible to use rowSpan to create a desired table. Not sure why your other question was unanswered, I just posted an answer on how to use rowSpan http://stackoverflow.com/a/27303000/297641

Comment: You can use something like in this answer to order a list of DOM nodes http://stackoverflow.com/a/3051100/2414886

Comment: thanks for your inputs, vega I will see how it goes and respond you to there and sarah I will have a look about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sorting handler: (the header classes need to be the same as where the info is, so changed in the header desc to Desc)

```
var sorting=1;
$(".Header div").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var cl=$(this).attr("class") // get header class, this is where I get info from
        sorting = sorting == 1 ? -1 : 1 ;         // sorting asc or desc
        $(".Info").detach().sort(function(a,b){
            var str1=$(a).find('.'+cl).text(); // get text
            var str2=$(b).find('.'+cl).text();
            var n1 = str1.match(/\d+/)[0] //get digits in text
            var n2 = str2.match(/\d+/)[0]
            if(n1 != '' ){ // if its a number
                return n1*sorting > n2*sorting; // sort by number
            }else{ // sort by string
                return sorting == 1 ? str1 > str2 : str1 < str2
            }
        }).appendTo($(".Header").parent());
    })
})
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/a4fcxzra/1/

Comment: very perfect, just changed the css style to Header .Desc and all good to go.. thanks again.

Comment: I got to some problems If I change any word from the the list it won't work.. for example this http://jsfiddle.net/a4fcxzra/3/ I made another item and called it gamepad and it won't sort.. how can I make it to sort regardless whichever word I put?

Comment: Well yeah, because I handled fields with numbers as numeric, so was sorting the items by 1,2,3,4,5. Added a function to overwrite that putting a `data-type='string'` in the header : http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/a4fcxzra/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an Array using JavaScript and then creating  tags dynamically to place them within the column headers (which you should create in the html for better performance)